# iPhone 6+ Responsive Image Viewport Bug (Unsemantic Grid)

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport, iphone-6, 960.gs

Here is the website: http://ch3.elance.website/en/

May you please help me fix the responsive images on iPhone6? What CSS is missing? Is this an *unsemantic grid iPhone 6+ responsive image bug* only?

When I test website on every other viewport, it's good. When my brother launched up his iPhone 6+ the images where not responsive. Using browser stack, I confirmed the issue.

Here are the sites I usually launch up to test viewport:

- http://quirktools.com/screenfly/
- http://mobiletest.me
- Native F12 Chrome Inspect Element

Here are three screenshots my brother sent me from his iPhone 6 using the Power + Home Button technique. If you visit the website in any of the above viewport tools, the site looks like it is working perfectly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an iPhone 6 Plus thing...  this is a mobile thing. It doesn't look like you've set your viewport intial-scale in the head.

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">`

Try that.

Comment: Hmm, I added that snippet to my header, but no change according to browsershot. Excellent suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

As @SeanStopnik suggested, you should add the meta tag in your `html` code :

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
</html>
```

The `viewport` tag was invented by Apple for the iPhone

You can find more information [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972)